# brother printer firmware update password reset

Tags: passwords, printer, network-printer, firmware

While trying to update my brother printer (DCP-8080DN) firmware, the java program asks for a admin password, and says that it could only have been altered by a BRadmin program, otherwise the default would be "access".

of course, if i am here, the default "access" was not accepted. And i bought this printer new a long time ago, and have never touched the firmware or even heard of a bradmin program until now.

Is there any way to see the current password on the panel? if not, would a factory reset via the menu restore the password to the default? if not, what will?

Comment: Just a thought, if the printer is connected to network you can try visiting http://<printer ip> and see if you can log in with default credentials - admin/access. I have not used BRAdmin program, but have used web interface for Brother MFC-7450 DN many times

Comment: In case the new answer gets muddled in all of this, the new default Brother password is 'initpass'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you might be able to reset to factory settings via the control panel on the device as well.

From [Brother's FAQ](http://support.brother.com/g/b/sp/faqend.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfc8480dn_us&faqid=faq00000105_008):

**Via the control panel** (only for network ready models)

1. Make sure the machine is not operating, then disconnect all the cables from the machine (except power cable).
2. Press the **Menu** or **Menu/Set** key on the control panel.
3. Press up or down navigation key to select **LAN or Network** and press **Set, Menu/Set** or **OK**.
4. Press up or down navigation key to select **Factory Reset** or **Network Reset** and press **Set, Menu/Set** or **OK**.
5. Select **Reset**.
6. Select **Yes**.
7. The machine will re-start, re-connect cables once this is complete.

Answer (score 19):

I spent many hours doing a variety of factory resets and trying the password above, "access". Apparently, Brother pushed out a firmware update recently which changed the default password on many devices to "initpass". So, if you are locked out of the web interface give this a try.

[help.brother-usa.com](https://help.brother-usa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/152494/~/default-network-password)

Comment: Boom! This was the answer I'm looking for. The default password was indeed "initpass". Thanks!